# Showing a field in ModelForm when it is being created but hiding it when it is being updated

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple ModelForm that looks like this:

```
class ProfInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True, label=_("Email")
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Prof
```

The `email` field is displayed when I'm creating or a updating a record using the model form but I'd like to remove it when I'm updating via the form. How can I do this? I know that I do a simple `del self.fields['email']` in the `__init__` method but how do I test whether it is being updated or deleted?

Comment: you could use django template language to check on which view is being called and then either display part of the form or not ...                  {% if .... %}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether form.instance.pk exists.

Something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfInfo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk:
        del self.field['email']
```